# Is it possible to dynamically construct jOOQ VALUES() table?

Tags: java, jooq

https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/values/

It's great that jOOQ supports the VALUES() table constructor, but it looks like the rows cannot be dynamically constructed. I have a list of rows that I would like to dynamically pass into VALUES(), is this possible with jOOQ?

Example: array of (1,2,3,4,5) and would like to construct VALUES(row(1), row(2) ... row(5)) from the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array to the `values()` method.

So simply iterate over your array and create a row per element, add this to an array and finally pass the array with the rows to the values method.